# Получения точного домена через PHP скрипт

Tags: php

У меня есть .php скрипт на хосте. Я хочу чтобы при начале его выполнения я мог узнать с какого домена был отправлен запрос на выполнение этого скрипта. 
То есть, к примеру есть site.com, на нём лежит файл file.php
А также есть work.com, с которого я подключаю http://site.com/file.php.
И в этом скрипте, при выполнении я хочу узнать, с какого домена пришёл запрос на выполнение.

Либо же есть .htaccess правило которое запрещает выполнение скриптов с других доменов, разрешая только для определённого домена?

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем, но может быть вам нужна защита от CSRF? https://habr.com/ru/post/318748/

Answer (score 1):

Самое главное что надо понимать про то, как работают сайты в интернете:

**Запросы приходят не с доменов.** Запросы приходят **из браузера клиента.** При этом браузер может, по желанию, сообщить, на каком сайте стояла ссылка, по которой он сейчас перешёл. А может и не сообщать. А может просто подделать и написать какой угодно.

Поэтому делать подобную защиту довольно бессмысленно. Смышлёного пятиклассника она не остановит.